# swift ios pass data between controllers

Tags: ios, swift, segue

I am trying to pass data between 2 controllers, to be more precise there is a button that segue's from a UIViewController to a UITableViewController that has a variable datadefine, when I try to print the datadefine variable its always blank although I am setting it in the prepareForSegue function, below is the code for the same

```
//
//  VC1.swift
//  TableViewSearchInSwift
//
//  Created by melwyn.p on 24/03/16.
//  Copyright © 2016 TheAppGururz. All rights reserved.
//

import UIKit

class VC1: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
        let dataViewController = segue.destinationViewController as! SearchViewController
        dataViewController.defineData = "data1"  
        print("test")      
    } 

}
```

below is the code for the searchViewController, also this was the main view at first which has been switched to be the second view now which popups up on button click

```
//
//  SearchViewController.swift
//  TableViewSearchInSwift
//
//  Created by TheAppGuruz-iOS-103 on 24/12/15.
//  Copyright © 2015 TheAppGururz. All rights reserved.
//

import UIKit

class SearchViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UISearchDisplayDelegate, UISearchBarDelegate
{

    var marrCountryList = [String]()
    var marrFilteredCountryList = [String]()
    var defineData  =   String()
    var file    =   String()


    @IBOutlet var tblCountry: UITableView!

    override func viewDidLoad()
    {
        print(defineData)

        super.viewDidLoad()
        var text=""


        print(defineData)




        if  defineData == "data1"
        {
             file = "/data1.txt"
        }
        else
        {
             file = "/data2.txt"
        }


        do{
              text = try String(contentsOfFile: file, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)



                    }
        catch
        {
            print(error);
            //contentsOfFile = nil;
        } 
        marrCountryList = text.componentsSeparatedByString("\n")
        self.tblCountry.reloadData()
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int
    {
        if tableView == self.searchDisplayController!.searchResultsTableView {
            return self.marrFilteredCountryList.count
        } else {
            return self.marrCountryList.count
        }
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
    {
        let cellCountry = self.tblCountry.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath)

        var countryName : String!
        if tableView == self.searchDisplayController!.searchResultsTableView {
            countryName = marrFilteredCountryList[indexPath.row]
        } else {
            countryName = marrCountryList[indexPath.row]
        }

        cellCountry.textLabel?.text = countryName.componentsSeparatedByString("%%")[0]

        return cellCountry
    }
    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

        print(defineData)
    }

    func filterTableViewForEnterText(searchText: String) {
        let searchPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "SELF CONTAINS[c] %@", searchText)

        let array = (self.marrCountryList as NSArray).filteredArrayUsingPredicate(searchPredicate)
        self.marrFilteredCountryList = array as! [String]
        self.tblCountry.reloadData()
    }


    func searchDisplayController(controller: UISearchDisplayController, shouldReloadTableForSearchString searchString: String?) -> Bool {
        self.filterTableViewForEnterText(searchString!)
        return true
    }

    func searchDisplayController(controller: UISearchDisplayController,
        shouldReloadTableForSearchScope searchOption: Int) -> Bool {
            self.filterTableViewForEnterText(self.searchDisplayController!.searchBar.text!)
            return true
    }
}
```

Comment: Whereabouts are you printing the data in the `SearchViewController`? can you show more code?

Comment: I have added the CODE to the segue view, also note that I also have tried to print "test" in the prepareforsegue function which doesn not print anything but segue's to the next view

Comment: Looks like your real problem is that `prepareForSegue` isn't called.

Comment: yea true, I am unable to understand why but yet the segue happens successfully

Comment: In which are class are you overriding prepareForSegue: and is it the same class in which you've created a storyboard segue?

Comment: Are you set your segue action on button click in storyboard?

Comment: @Jeff Originally the searchViewController was the entry point later I added a new UIviewController (that contains the button segue) connected it with class VC1.swift and added a prepareForSegue within VC1 which doesnt seem to be working

Comment: @seto I'm not sure what exactly you meant by "set segue action" but I simply ctrl+dragged onto the next view to create the segue

Comment: From where did you ctrl+dragged your segue? from first view controller's view or from your button? IIRC, if your button is the anchor of the segue it won't call `prepareForSegue` function.

Comment: Can you set a breakpoint in prepareForSegue to check if it is called and can you add a screenshot of your segue and its properties?

Comment: @seto yes I dragged it from the button, is that the reason for the prepareforsegue to not being called?? @ Jeff will add a breakpoint and share a screenshot of segue's properties

Comment: @Jeff added a breakpoint for check, it seems the function is never called

Comment: @melwynpawar Please post your Storyboard where you set up the segue

Comment: @Jeff I just seen your comment, meanwhile I re-added the class and ViewController and re-created the segue and it seems to be working now, not sure though what the original issue was

Answer (score -3):

You cannot print it in viewDidLoad. viewDidLoad only gets executed once and it happens before prepareForSeque fires. Move it to viewWillAppear.

```
override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    print(defineData)    
}
```

Comment: As far as I know, `viewDidLoad` is called AFTER `prepareForSegue` is called.

Comment: That can't be true. The view controller object MUST be instantiated before it can be provided in prepareFroSegue. There is NO WAY is can be called after.

Answer (score -3):

you should use the didSet internal function that called immediately after the new value is stored.

try this on SearchViewController class:

```
var defineData: String! {
    didSet(defineData) {
        self.defineData = defineData
    }
}
```

when you do this:

```
let dataViewController = segue.destinationViewController as! SearchViewController
dataViewController.defineData = "data1"
```

the `dataViewController` variable isn't an actual object
and that's why you can't compare this

```
dataViewController.defineData = "data1"
```

because the `defineData` of `dataViewController` object isn't exist

but when you use the didSet internal function you are saying that the value will set immediately ufter that the `dataViewController` object will be an actual object.

if you want to learn more, check out this link: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Properties.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH14-ID254